# Burnside's Lemma, applications

Tags: combinatorics

> A relation $\sim$ on $C$ is equivalence if it is:
>
> - reflexive: $c\sim c$ for all colorings $c$ belonging to $C$
> - symmetric: $c_1\sim c_2$ implies $c_2\sim c_1$
> - transitive: $c_1\sim c_2$  and $c_2\sim c_3$ implies $c_1\sim c_3$
>
> A set of objects $S$, a set of colorings of these objects $C$ and a group of permutations $G$ representing symmetries possessed by configurations of the objects. Two colorings in $C$ are equivalent if there is a permutation in $G$ that transforms a coloring into the other.

Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $C$. How do you prove that?

As well as that, prove that $G_c$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

It’s pretty straightforward; everything follows from the definition of *group of permutations*.

- Reflexivity: Since $G$ is a group, it contains the identity permutation, which transforms any coloring into itself.
- Symmetry: If there is a permutation $g\in G$ transforming a coloring $c_1$ into $c_2$, the inverse permutation $g^{-1}$, which must be in $G$, transforms $c_2$ to $c_1$.
- Transitivity: If there are permutations $g,h\in G$ transforming $c_1$ to $c_2$ and $c_2$ to $c_3$, respectively, they their group product $hg$, which necessarily belongs to $G$, transforms $c_1$ to $c_3$: it’s just a composition of functions.

Answer (score 1):

You have a group $G$ (here the symmetric group of permutations) acting on a set $C$. The relation in question is defined as $c_1\sim c_2\iff \exists g\in G\colon c_1=gc_2$. Such is always an equivalence relation because $G$ is a group (neutral element gives reflexivity, inverse gives symmetry, the group operation gives transitivity). *Remark:* The equivalence classes in such a case are called *orbits* of an element under the group action.

If $c\in C$ we call $G_c:=\{g\in G\mid gc=c\}$ the *stabilizer* or *fixgroup* of $c$.
It is a group because the neutral element fixes $c$, the inverse of $g$ fixes $c$ if $g$ fixes $c$ and if both  $g_1 $ and $g_2$ fix $c$ then so does theit composition $g_1g_2$.

Comment: How would you do the second part? proof that Gc is a subgroup of G.

Comment: @Max $Gc$ is not a soubgroup of $G$, it is an orbit withn $C$, isn't it?

Comment: http://gyazo.com/c6d513e5e79bcccbb2d1056cf0420abe this is all I've found that might shed a light on the situation..

Comment: Oh, then why don't you write $G_c$ instead of $Gc$? What they write there as $\bar c$ is what I denoted $Gc$ - the orbit of $c$, whereas $G_c$ is the stabilizer.

Comment: A subgroup you mean? and if it was to make it more mathematical, would there be a way?

Comment: What do you mean with more mathematical? I wrote my answer so that you can *understand* what happens and get an *insight*. I did not wanted to shoot at you with quantor-garbled first-order logic statements ...

Comment: Haha, and I appreciate it very much but if you could you could give me the quality math stuff too, it looks fancy on paper.

Comment: It should be easy for you to do that yourself based on my remarks above.